# how to disable slidetoggle (wordpress)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, search, slidetoggle, searchbar

thank you for reading through my question (i am very new to the community so please forgive me if i make any mistakes)

so basically i have a wordpress theme that i have purchased and i am wondering how to disable the sliding transition on the search box as i would like it to snap instantly rather than have a slow transition. i have tried searching through the css of my theme file and there is nothing . i have managed to find in the scripts.js file that it has slidetoggle and i think thats the problem for the slow transitions. how can this be edited to make the transition instant? thank you.

```
// Search Toggle
$("#search-button").click(function(){
  $("#search-bar").slidetoggle();
});
```

Comment: by the sounds of it you do not want sliding animation. Why not change it to use .toggle() instead of .slideToggle() - http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Thank you very much , I tried that at first but I realised I made a small typo, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead.

Change:

```
$("#search-bar").slidetoggle();
```

To:

```
$("#search-bar").toggle();
```

This will make the animation "instant" rather than a "slide" animation.